# ComboBox in a ListBox fires SelectionChanged event but value of the selected item of combo box doesnt get updated - MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, win-universal-app

I have a UWP app, using the Prism framework\toolkit. The app has a ListView. Every row composites of various TextBlocks and a ComboBox. Initially, when the grid gets loaded, I want ComboBox to show no item selected but the item source loaded. The user now has to choose any item from the combo box. The ListBox and ComboBox are populated from 2 different ObservableCollection from the ViewModel. The SelectionChanged event does fire for me for the ComboBoxes in the ListBox as I am using Dependency Property but the item which is selected by the user from Combo Box, the properly of Selected Value is not updating in the View Model.
I have a ListView within which I have ComboBox.

I have added the code-snippet from my application below:

I am using Behaviors SDK here as well.

```
    <ListView x:Name="AssignCountryStateGridData"  Grid.Row="1" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding AssignCCPGridInfo,Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="805"  MinHeight="480">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  MinHeight="25" MinWidth="805">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CompanyCode}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding CompanyCode}"  TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CustomerNbr}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding CustomerNumber}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Height="25"  Width="20" Margin="20,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="comboBoxCountryCode" 
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.EFSSAPCountryCode,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="CountryCode"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCountryCode,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=AssignCountryStateGridData,Path=DataContext.LoadSelectedCountryCodeCommand}" 
                                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue,ElementName= AssignCountryStateGridData}"/>
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </ComboBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And this is View Model Code

```
 private ObservableCollection<EFSSAPCountryCode> _EFSSAPCountryCode;
        private EFSSAPCountryCode _SelectedCountryCode;
        public DelegateCommand LoadSelectedCountryCodeCommand { get; set; }

        [RestorableState]
        public ObservableCollection<EFSSAPCountryCode> EFSSAPCountryCode
        {
            get { return _EFSSAPCountryCode; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _EFSSAPCountryCode, value); }
        }
        [RestorableState]
        public EFSSAPCountryCode SelectedCountryCode
        {
            get { return _SelectedCountryCode; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _SelectedCountryCode, value); }
        }

        public AssignCountryStateProvinceCodesViewModel()
        {
            this.LoadSelectedCountryCodeCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(GetColumnsForSelectedCountryCode);
        }

        public async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
        {
            //Set EFSSAPCountryCode and other call for service
        }

        private async Task GetColumnsForSelectedCountryCode()
        {
            //I am getting call here when I select something from Combo Box but I never get what was selected by the user from the Combo Box and "SelectedCountryCode" stays null
        }
```

I saw something about using RelativeSource but that gives syntax error.

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}
```

I am not sure what is wrong in this code.

Comment: in Set you are not calling NotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: I inherit BindableBase abstract class which is inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged. And here I have pasted one small part of that while. The notify property is working fine for all other 100 of controls in my application

Comment: @Stamos - That didnt help either

Comment: Does the Command triggers? Have you trying putting a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes...the Command is getting triggered. My breakpoint is getting hit. But my property SelectedCountryCode is not getting set.

Comment: I am finding the same behavior in my code.

Comment: Hey Jerry, were you able to find the fix or any workaround for this issue?